# Hide my WCF Method

Tags: wcf, service, hide

I have a self hosted WCF service. Now if someone wants he/she can easily create a proxy and use my Methods. How to protect this thing. I want nobody outside my project can uses my Method. Please help me.

Comment: You should be more specific: tell us what your *relevant* code and configuration look like, and what you've tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: I am using basicHttpbinding. I create a proxy of my service and  accessing the methods using C#. Now i want that outside my project no one will be able to create the proxy and use my Methods. Or he or she can create my proxy but cannot access my methods. Is it possible? I tried security mode="Transport" but not success. Please help me. I cant change my BasicHttpBinding. It is already used in various project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure WCF service and Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319867/secure-wcf-service-and-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed in many times.

One option you can be authenticate the clients using a username/password and protect the connection using ssl. This is good if the connection is over the internet.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265635/easiest-way-to-protect-wcf-services), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648840.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/8-steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba)